# Steelbrick/Salesforce CPQ - Customize the pricing in quote line editor

Tags: community, customer-community, cpq

My company just started using Salesforce CPQ and we have a structure for furniture manufacturing.

We have 3 types of products with product family:

- Furniture
- Fabric
- Leggings

The **furniture product** has dimensions that are depending of the fabric(fabric required)

[image]

He has information about the leggings required and the fabric required depending on the width of the fabric.

The **fabric product** has fields that shows the width of the fabric and the price.

[image]

Because the company will add new products fabric/furniture we have made a Dynamic Bundle that will gather all the furniture and fabric.

Below I am just showing the setup for one of the filters. Others are basically the same.

[image]

The structure inside the Quote Line Editor looks like this.

[image]

and inside the bundle the structure looks like this.
[image]

So as you can see first we pick the furniture type then we pick the fabric and last the leggings.

What we want to achieve is that every time a furniture is picked we gather the values of the meters needed for the fabric and when we select the fabric after an automatic calculation needs to occur.

Fabric gathers the fabric width and fabric price
Furniture gathers fab required meters depending of the width of the fabric.

Let me explain it even further.
When I pick a fabric the fabric gathers the data of the

> width: 140

for example, and then checks

> Fab. Req m(140): 5.6

what occurs next is automatic calculation:

> 5.6 * fabric price * 1.2 * 1.4

*The values 1.2 and 1.4 are just automatically calculated fixed numbers.*

How can we achieve this in the quote line editor for this automatic calculation to be calculated every time i pick a different fabric or different furniture prices to change?

Here is more info that I wrote in the salesforce community regarding my problem.
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000imWHQAY

The price rules are so confusing for me. I don't know where to start and what to do.Here is what I did so far.
[image]

Thanks,

Darko

Answer (score 0):

I would say that

a) you might want to consider having quantity for fabric be measured in number of meters so you can have an automatic calculation based off of list price

b) It's not clear where your values of 1.2 and 1.4 are coming from. (I assume they are dynamically pulled from somewhere since you're not just increasing by 1.68?) If this is just a markup, you might want to populate the discount with a negative percentage

c) What you are probably looking for is a [Price Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_price_rules_intro.htm&type=5).

For your use case, you'd probably do something like:

1. Check for that variable in the error condition of a price rule
2. If it exists, update the fields you want with a price action and a formula (you can try creating the formula in a formula field first to validate the syntax)

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1IbG.jpg) an example of what your rule might look like

If you find that what you're trying to do is too complicated for a price rule, you can always use a [Quote Calculator Plugin](http://www.buanconsulting.com/steelbrick-quote-calculator-plugins/)

Comment: Hi brezotom,
Thank you for your reply. Let me give you more details of what I did so far in the edited version of the question.

Comment: If you have some spare time to help me out i will provide everything you need regarding this topic.

Comment: @DarkoTodorovski it should look something like this: https://imgur.com/a/DquSFSM

Comment: @DarkoTodorovski, did you have any luck with this?

Comment: not really bro. I tried everything and i quit it in the process :(